# While performing inline edit on table cell value in DB Console of IntelliJ, it shows Table is read-only

Tags: database, intellij-idea

I am running a query in IntelliJ DB Console. When I try to change the cell value, I am getting a warning message like *Table is read-only*.
so I am unable to update the record in the database.

[image]

Comment: Please try: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-8795/Table-is-read-only-Unresolved-table-reference#focus=Comments-27-6281640.0-0

Answer (score 3):

For this problem, you need to select the database.

Perform the below steps to resolve your issue:

1. Menubar > View > Tool Windows > Select Database
2. In Database Window > Expand your Database connection
3. Select the Database > Right click on it
4. Select the 'New Query Console' option (in Updated Intellij, New > Query Console)
5. Execute your query in the opened Console window
6. Go to the Output tab, try to edit any cell value, you will not get the warning message.

[image: New Query Console]